# Ingesting parquet files to landing zone

Tags: parquet, azure-data-lake, data-ingestion

We are working with Azure cloud and we have some pipelines which ingest daily data from sap to azure data lake gen 2. We were working with Azure Data Factory ingesting json and csv files but maybe is better change our approach and ingest parquet files to landing zone and then move to trusted zone using delta tables.

What do you think? is a good idea ingesting raw data to landing in parquet format?